# Proper usage of terms for a webapp

Tags: web-app, terminology, information-architecture, profile

I've been tasked to wireframe a user management component for multiple applications and was having a concern about the proper naming of the included sections.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCsq68.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

In the above wireframe, the user can select the menu entry *Profile Settings* to view the profile settings page. There are sub-sections and I've used *profile* as the first sub-section which will consist of basic profile settings such as username, first name, last name, etc.

Does it make more sense to use *default* as the sub-section name rather than *profile*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think profile is definitely better label than "default", because it is more commonly used in other web applications, so users will have some idea what it is before clicking.

Just to be clear:

1) Is the profile page going to include option to edit settings of your profile?

2) If so, what will the settings on the "profile settings" page be? Listing these out can be really useful!

Why not label the "profile settings" link as more generic "settings", you will probably anyways end up putting other settings there, such as preferences and security/privacy etc.

If some settings are changed through the profile page, you can always link to them on the settings page. For example "To change your username, please go to **the profile page**"

Comment: My approach was to name the link as "Account Settings" since it consists of profile settings + some general settings. Which makes much more sense other than profile settings. So in that case, using "Profile" as the secondary navigation makes much more sense.

Comment: Sounds good! However I think you could also get away with using just "settings", it seems to be the convention anyway. Just look at any website that you frequently visit. :)

Comment: Yes I referred to couple of famous websites and they all use settings as the link so I guess a better approach would be to use that way. :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to use *default* because this communicates nothing to the user. It doesn't make sense to use *profile* because *profile* already describes a concept in the application.

Try *profile details*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write it as

**Account Settings** or **My Account** which can have further 
SubTabs like

1) Security (Public and private stuffs ,Sign In) Card

2) Password (Change password) Card

3) Profile ( Change profile photo and short description of user) Card

4) Account Preferences Card

And i think you should use **card layout** to show these after clicking on **Account Settings** or **My Account** button

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> Does it make more sense to use default as the sub-section name rather than profile?

In what context do you mean?

If you mean, does it make sense to name the view 'default' when speaking to a developer? - possibly.

When talking to a customer? - probably not, unless this is a customers understanding of the section.

I would always try to find a common language with the customer so you're on the same page (pun intended) when talking about areas of the app.